# Class A instance running methods from class B instance that called Class A wothout retain cycles

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, callback

I have an instance of my LayerClass (Scene1.M) that generates moving seas, clouds etc. This creates an instance of my Parachutist.M class to make a sprite parachute into the sea. Once there I want the parachutist instance to call some methods in Scene1.M class. I have this working by Scene1.M calling 
parachutist = [Parachutist createParachutist:self];

In Parachutist.h createParachutist is defined as +(id) createParachutist:(id)parentID;
The Parachutist instance can run methods from Scene1.M via [parentID method1] etc and this works.
The question is when I transition to a new scene I've realised that Scene1.M instance is not released because createParachutist instance has ownership so I have a retain cycle. I've read about __weak but ARC doesn't seem to allow it. I've researched callbacks and delegates but can't see what to use. 
All I want is to pass the ID of Scene1 instance to Parachutist instance without creating a retain cycle but allowing parachutist to call methods in Scene1.

---

Thanks very much Vladimir and Rob for confirming that __weak should work with ARC. I'd been so busy focusing on delegates/callback etc that it was only when you confirmed ARC should allow __weak that I delved deeper and found my deployment target was 4.6x. Once I changed that to 5  then __weak was allowed and this has solved the problem

Comment: __weak was introduced in ARC so it should be available. Post your code may be, so people can point to mistakes?

Comment: The `weak` references not only work in ARC, but require ARC. The only caveat is that it requires iOS 5.0 or higher (if you're trying to support iOS versions prior to 5, you have to use `unsafe_unretained` in lieu of `weak`, but as the name suggests, you have to be careful, just as you were in the pre-ARC days). Bottom line, yes, the parachutist should have a `weak` reference back to the scene. As long as it's not a `strong` reference, you should be ok.